# Convert String To date in PHP

Tags: php, string, unix-timestamp

How can I convert this string `05/Feb/2010:14:00:01` to unixtime ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For PHP 5.3 this should work. You may need to fiddle with passing $dateInfo['is_dst'], wasn't working for me anyhow.

```
$date = '05/Feb/2010:14:00:01';
$dateInfo = date_parse_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $date);
$unixTimestamp = mktime(
    $dateInfo['hour'], $dateInfo['minute'], $dateInfo['second'],
    $dateInfo['month'], $dateInfo['day'], $dateInfo['year'],
    $dateInfo['is_dst']
);
```

Versions prior, this should work.

```
$date = '05/Feb/2010:14:00:01';
$format = '@^(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<month>[A-Z][a-z]{2})/(?P<year>\d{4}):(?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<minute>\d{2}):(?P<second>\d{2})$@';
preg_match($format, $date, $dateInfo);
$unixTimestamp = mktime(
    $dateInfo['hour'], $dateInfo['minute'], $dateInfo['second'],
    date('n', strtotime($dateInfo['month'])), $dateInfo['day'], $dateInfo['year'],
    date('I')
);
```

You may not like regular expressions. You could annotate it, of course, but not everyone likes that either. So, this is an alternative.

```
$day = $date[0].$date[1];
$month = date('n', strtotime($date[3].$date[4].$date[5]));
$year = $date[7].$date[8].$date[9].$date[10];
$hour = $date[12].$date[13];
$minute = $date[15].$date[16];
$second = $date[18].$date[19];
```

Or substr, or explode, whatever you wish to parse that string.

Comment: It is not working at all. It says date_parse_from_format is un-defined.

Answer (score 54):

Use the `strtotime` function:

**Example:**

```
 $date = "25 december 2009";
 $my_date = date('m/d/y', strtotime($date));
 echo $my_date;
```

Comment: @streetparade: i mean for example you can not pass to it all sorts of strings for the date eg "28 of the December two thousand ten"

Comment: It's worth noting strtotime also supports key words and phrases like 'yesterday' or 'this day next week' ;p

Answer (score 4):

You should look into the [strtotime() function](https://www.php.net/strtotime).

Comment: Your string might not be compatible with strtotime(); you might have to format it a little first.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.php.net/date_parse_from_format

Answer (score 2):

```
$d="05/Feb/2010:14:00:01";
$dr= date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $d);
echo $dr->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

here you get date string, give format specifier in ->format() according to format needed

Answer (score 1):

Simple exploding should do the trick:

```
$monthNamesToInt = array('Jan'=>1,'Feb'=>2, 'Mar'=>3 /*, [...]*/ );
$datetime = '05/Feb/2010:14:00:01';
list($date,$hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':',$datetime);
list($day,$month,$year) = explode('/',$date);

$unixtime = mktime((int)$hour, (int)$minute, (int)$second, $monthNamesToInt[$month], (int)$day, (int)$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for it, use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_date=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This is downvoted due to redundancy.  The answer itself is correct, but was previously provided on Feb 8 by Sarfraz.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string that you trust meaning that you have checked it before hand then the following would also work.

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-03-27');
```

Comment: problem with DateTime is that will convert the timezone.