# i want php pattern for date as DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression to use in `preg_match` to check whether or not a date is in the pattern `DD/MM/YYYY`. I tried the code below, but it didn't work:

```
preg_match("#^[1-31]*1[1-12]*1[1950-2013]?#", $date);
```

Comment: pretty much everything about it is wrong.

Comment: This is really poor question, think about others taking their time to answer your question. Please be more patient before asking questions. There's no effort visible in this question.

Comment: And it's not exactly hard to google either. Possible duplicate of [What is the MM/DD/YYYY regular expression and how do I use it in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520633/what-is-the-mm-dd-yyyy-regular-expression-and-how-do-i-use-it-in-php)

Comment: but now i have Charles Hooper's answer it is : date_parse_from_format('d/M/Y', $date); >>> it is good answer it's helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match("/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/",$date);` however a regex isn't well-suited for this task because there you will still need to perform additional validation ("9999" is a valid year, for example). I think instead you may want to take a look at `date_parse_from_format()`, like:

```
date_parse_from_format('d/M/Y', $date);
```

See [Convert String To date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222851/convert-string-to-date-in-php) for more information.

Comment: this is goog but also i want to sure from years is between 1900 && 2013 how i can do this

Answer (score 4):

Your regex translates to:

> - From the start of the string,
> - Look for any number of characters in the range 1 through 3, or the character 1
> - Look for a literal 1
> - Look for any number of characters in the range 1 through 1, or the character 2
> - Look for a literal 1
> - Look for either one or zero of the characters 1, 9, 5, 0 through 2, 0, 1 or 3

It very obviously doesn't make sense.

You can't validate a date in regex, since dates are not regular. You have different numbers of days in each month, leap years, and a bunch of other stuff. You would be better off separating your date into pieces (use `explode`) and check it with [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/checkdate)

Comment: "You can't validate a date in regex" - actually we can generate all the possible valid dates in a particular range and combine them with `|`

Comment: I won't be surprised that someone used that sometime. People wonder me every day with terrible solutions they choose to solve their problems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is so wrong that I don't even know where to start explaining.

But the simplest answer is: don't use regex for this. PHP has perfectly good date handling routines already. For example, `DateTime::createFromFormat()`...

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $dateString);
echo $date->format('j-M-Y');  //outputs something like '15-Feb-2009'
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php