# how to get php date format from given string

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

How to get date format of given string, string contain a valid date
I am try to import data from csv file, and that csv files are exported for backup
but there are so many different type of date format and in some case when i try to convert string to date it throwing me an error

> ex: 04/08/2010 10:22 am

some time this **type** of format throwing me error

```
Error 500: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
```

Comment: So is 04/08/2010 the 4th of August, or the 8th of April? A little bit of reading about DateTime objects in the manual might have pointed you to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php and to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: There's hardly an automatic way to do that. DateTime already tries to identify various date formats automatically, it just fails on ones it doesn't know. You'll need to prepare a list of possible formats and probably test against them with a Regex.

Comment: alias of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222851/convert-string-to-date-in-php

Answer (score 3):

You can use just [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('04/08/2010 10:22 am')); // output: 2010-04-08 10:22:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) static method.

Also, you may want to do some reading:

- [`DateTime::__construct()` reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
- [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)
- [Date/Time extension reference](http://php.net/dateTime)

Also, you need to use the search function (top right on the page). There are a lot of questions that deal with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...........

```
           $today = date("d/m/Y g:i a");

<?php 
    $today = date("d/m/Y g:i a");
    echo $today;
?>
```

You will get output like this.........`20/02/2013 7:53 am`

For sample one see this [example](http://eval.in/10799) link

Comment: Why throw somebody who's already using DateTime objects back to using the more problematic date functions?